# Set the highlight style of a link to "none" instead of "invert"

Tags: hyperref, pdf, links

I've read all documentation possible regarding **hyperref** but I still don't know how to **set the highlight style of a link to "none" instead of "invert"** (which is the default by the way).
Is there any other package that could deal with this, or is there any workaround to solve this?

Below is the Adobe Acrobat menu for hyperlinking something. As you can see the default for Highlight style is "invert". With hyperref is easy to change all other properties but how about highlight style?

Sometimes is awkward to click on an image that is linked since acrobat (for instance) displays it with the colours inverted when clicking (when the mouse button is down)...

Can someone help me out?
Thanks a lot!

Example file [here](http://fzs.sve-mo.ba/sites/default/files/dokumenti-vijesti/sample.pdf).
If you download the pdf file (because browsers display pdfs in a simpler manner) and open it in adobe reader and if you click (and leave the mouse button down) on a link you'l see that the colors will become inverted. If set the highlight style to none this will not happen. How to do it is the million dollar question? :)

[image: Adobe Acrobat menu for links]

Comment: What LaTeX IDE are you using?

Comment: PDFTex / PdfTextify is what I use to compile the document.

Comment: I mean: what program do you prepare your document in? Obviously, it runs on Windows, but what is it? This information will probably help people here answer your question.

Comment: Sorry!
Then the correct anser is WinEdt! :)
But does that make difference?
The posted image is from what you get from doing the link in adobe acrobat and is not from any Latex IDE... Sorry for the confusion. I'll change the image title or something.

Comment: Pedro, just to clarify: you want to change the style of links from within Adobe Acrobat; not from inside WinEdt. Correct?

Comment: No... I intend to change the highlight style from within Latex.
Can't hyperref handle this option? It can for sure handle, colors, styles, etc. But I can't find a way to change this option in hyperref (or any other package, for that matter)...

Comment: Ok, I think I understand now. I don't know about this "invert" option. A search in the `hyperref` manual returns nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Default for option `pdfhighlight` is `/I` for "Invert". It can be changed to "None":

```
\hypersetup{pdfhighlight=/N}
```

Other values:

- `/O`: "Outline"
- `/P`: "Push"

See [PDF specification](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html). `hyperref` is only passing the values through to the link dictionary.

From [`PDF32000_2008.pdf`](https://wwwimages2.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf):

> ### Table 173 – Additional entries specific to a link annotation
>
> - **Key:** **`H`**
> - **Type:** name
> - **Description:** (Optional; PDF 1.2) The annotation’s highlighting mode, the visual effect that shall be used when the mouse button is
>     pressed or held down inside its active area:
>
>   **`N`** (None) No highlighting.
>     **`I`** (Invert) Invert the contents of the annotation rectangle.
>     **`O`** (Outline) Invert the annotation’s border.
>     **`P`** (Push) Display the annotation as if it were being pushed below the surface of the page.
>     Default value: **`I`**.

Comment: Thanks a lot again Heiko!!
Really appreciate your quick and accurate answer!

Thanks also to Jubobs for helping me to clarify the question!