# Change the on-click link colors with hyperref

Tags: hyperref, pdf, viewers

Consider the following MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[10pt]{report}
\usepackage[hidelinks,draft=false,linkcolor=black,pdfusetitle,pdfdisplaydoctitle]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Motivation}
\end{document}
```

If I click and hold a link in the Table of Contents, I get this:

[image]
[image]

The first picture is if I open the PDF using Foxit reader and the second is in Adobe Reader. Is it possible to change these on-click colors? Or rather, force the viewer to display the ones I want?

Edit: while the example shows links in the ToC, the same colors are used for in-text citations/section references as well.

Edit 2: It's partially viewer dependent. I've updated the question accordingly

Comment: You should probably list which viewer you're using. I fir one, have never seen colors like that when interacting with a pdf

Comment: That was a good tip. I'll update the question

Comment: It might have something to do with the `/H` key in PDF standard. See Table 173 of https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf#page=403

Comment: So would this key be set in the document or in the viewer? If it were in the document, I'd expect viewers conforming to the standard to be consistent in its display. But Adobe Reader shows the color inversion (option I), the Chrome PDF viewer shows nothing (option N), and Foxit doesn't seem to be doing either

Comment: Thanks to @Symbol1's comment, I found this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176907/set-the-highlight-style-of-a-link-to-none-instead-of-invert. I guess custom colors aren't possible but it is a little controllable

Comment: One possibility for more control: put a red background outside the link, put a blue background inside the link, with opacity .5. Now the link has purple background. Upon clicking, only the blue is inverted; red is still red. So the clicking color is orangish. (Sorry I am bad at color arithmetic.)